# Creating custom documents (PDFs) on the fly on a website

Tags: linux, web, latex

I want to create custom documents on my website which is running on a Linux-based server. My website has user login capability to access specific details on the website.

What I want to do is:

1. Use a default `.tex` file where the contents of the main document are stored. This would be available on the server (on admin side);
2. Get few user specific inputs (like login name, the day and date when the request was made), their custom inputs like what specific details they want (this will make it possible to include or exclude few chapters, sections from the document);
3. Using the inputs received above (in point 2), the document would be customized on the fly on the website by running LaTeX compiler and the output of the compilation would be shared with the user.

My questions are:

1. Has someone tried this before? Any suggestions, alternatives they can point to? If there is any other better solution than LaTeX, I am open to hear and understand that as well.
2. Are there any specific settings that we need to do either on the server or on LaTeX installation that will enable doing this?
3. Any additional packages, programs are required to be installed to get this working?

Any help and insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Just how much user input is there? LaTeX input is a program, so much care needs to be taken when sanitizing it. You could generate a document with the chapters you want first, as a PDF form, and then fill that form with `pdftk`, that feels safer to me, but it depends on your use case.

Comment: The user input is just selection of sections (that he wishes to see in the document). This would be handled by a web interface. This input would be transferred to latex (by recreating the base input *.tex file which will have commands to only include sections that the user asks for. In addition to this, the header and footer of the document will contain the name of the user who requested this. So the output pdf becomes a completely customized document for the user.

Comment: That sounds good enough, since you probably take a sanitized username from your database already.

Comment: I'm not sure about the LaTex layer, but the whole thing could be done over the web using Ruby and the [combine_pdf](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf) gem. If you had the chapters and main document in PDF format (a template), you could simply add any text using the #textbox method with combine_pdf. You could also combine the PDF files using the same gem.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate PDF using appropriate libraries for programming language you use for your back-end. This is definitely safer than injecting user input into TeX file and probably would be faster too.

- PHP: [Best way to create a PDF with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132015/best-way-to-create-a-pdf-with-php)
- Ruby: https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn
- anything else: google for "$LANGUAGE generate pdf".

Answer (score 1):

The first and the second questions can be done in any programming language you choose while reading the .tex template and add/omit the data, then save it to the temporal .tex file. After compilation yo can remove this file. If you are working with a linux server you can use a service (cron, systemd) to automate the cleaning of files.

To compile and get the file you must use pdflatex command line program, which is the one any LaTeX editor uses. I compile my LaTeX documents this way in linux. I think this way is quite fast, except if you want images in this document, or are using tikz pictures.

I know I am suggesting the old way to do the work, but usually is the best way.

And, finally, I think PHDComics uses something like this for the emergency  button (down in the right), only that in the site the pdf is already generated for the specific comic: http://www.phdcomics.com/